# Drag and Drop Template using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop, draggable

After Dragging a block from left container to right container, it gets removed from left container. How to prevent from removing from left container and should drag and drop multiple times the same?

I have tried with this code and it's not working for me.

Need to achieve - It Shouldn't get remove after dragging to right container it should be always there to drag multiple times

```js
const blocksData = [{
    id: 1,
    label: 'Test Content',
    htmlContent: '<h1>Test Content</h1>'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    label: 'Test Content',
    htmlContent: '<h2>Test Content</h2>'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    label: 'Test Content',
    htmlContent: '<h3>Test Content</h3>'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    label: 'Test Content',
    htmlContent: '<button>Test Content</button>'
  },
];
const getDragAfterElement = (container, y) => {
  console.log("Test 1");
  const draggableElements = [...container.querySelectorAll('.block:not(.dragging)')]
  return draggableElements.reduce((closest, child) => {
    const box = child.getBoundingClientRect()
    const offset = y - box.top - box.height / 2
    if (offset < 0 && offset > closest.offset) {
      return {
        offset: offset,
        element: child
      }
    } else {
      return closest
    }
  }, {
    offset: Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY
  }).element
}
const initiateHandler = () => {
  console.log("Test 2");
  const left = document.getElementsByClassName("left")[0];
  const handle = document.getElementById("handle");
  handle.draggable = true;
  handle.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
    ismdwn = 1
    document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => mV(e, left))
    document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => end(e, handle))
  });
}
const onReady = () => {
  console.log("Test 3");
  initiateHandler();
  const drggableBlocksHolder = document.getElementById("blocks");
  blocksData.map((block) => {
    if (!document.querySelector("#blocks > div:nth-child(4)")) drggableBlocksHolder.innerHTML += `<div draggable="true" class="block" data-block="${block.id}">${block.htmlContent}</div>`;
  });
  document.right = document.getElementsByClassName("right")[0];
  document.draggables = blocks.getElementsByClassName("block");
  document.draggable = document.querySelector('.dragging');
  for (let index = 0; index < document.draggables.length; index++) {
    const draggable = document.draggables[index];
    draggable.addEventListener('dragstart', () => {
      draggable.classList.add('dragging')
    });
    draggable.addEventListener('dragend', () => {
      draggable.classList.remove('dragging')
    });
  }
  document.right.addEventListener('dragover', (e) => {
    console.log("Test 4");
    e.preventDefault();
    document.draggables = blocks.getElementsByClassName("block");
    document.draggable = document.querySelector('.dragging');
    const afterElement = getDragAfterElement(document.right, e.clientY)
    if (afterElement == null) {
      id = document.draggable.getAttribute('data-block')
      document.draggable.innerHTML = blocksData[id - 1].htmlContent;
      document.right.appendChild(document.draggable)
    } else {
      document.right.insertBefore(document.draggable, afterElement)
    }
  });
};
const mV = (event, left) => {
  console.log("Test 5");
  if (ismdwn === 1) {
    left.style.flexBasis = event.clientX + "px"
  } else {
    end()
  }
}
const end = (e) => {
    console.log("Test 6");
    ismdwn = 0
    document.body.removeEventListener('mouseup', end)
    handle.removeEventListener('mousemove', mV)
  }
  (function() {
    console.log("Test 7");
    onReady()
  })();
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html {
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.container>.left {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 35%;
  min-width: 300px;
}

.container>.left>.blocks {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}

.container>.left>h4 {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 10px auto;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container>.left>.blocks>.block {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  cursor: move;
}

.block.dragging {
  opacity: .5;
}

.container>.right {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.container>.handle {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  content: '';
  width: 7px;
  cursor: col-resize;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <h4>Blocks</h4>
    <div class="blocks" id="blocks">
      <div draggable="true" class="block" data-block="1">Test Block 1 H1</div>
      <div draggable="true" class="block" data-block="2">Test Block 1 H2</div>
      <div draggable="true" class="block" data-block="3">Test Block 1 H3</div>
      <div draggable="true" class="block" data-block="4">Test Block 1 button</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="handle" id="handle"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is what you wanted. The reason the block was being deleted was because of the appendChild method. I replaced the child trying to be appended to a clone of the block that was being dragged. Please let me know if you need something else.

```js
const blocksData = [{
    id: 1,
    label: 'Test Content',
    htmlContent: '<h1>Test Content</h1>'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    label: 'Test Content',
    htmlContent: '<h2>Test Content</h2>'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    label: 'Test Content',
    htmlContent: '<h3>Test Content</h3>'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    label: 'Test Content',
    htmlContent: '<button>Test Content</button>'
  },
];
const getDragAfterElement = (container, y) => {
  console.log("Test 1");
  const draggableElements = [...container.querySelectorAll('.block:not(.dragging)')]
  return draggableElements.reduce((closest, child) => {
    const box = child.getBoundingClientRect()
    const offset = y - box.top - box.height / 2
    if (offset < 0 && offset > closest.offset) {
      return {
        offset: offset,
        element: child
      }
    } else {
      return closest
    }
  }, {
    offset: Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY
  }).element
}
const initiateHandler = () => {
  console.log("Test 2");
  const left = document.getElementsByClassName("left")[0];
  const handle = document.getElementById("handle");
  handle.draggable = true;
  handle.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
    ismdwn = 1
    document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => mV(e, left))
    document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => end(e, handle))
  });
}
const onReady = () => {
  console.log("Test 3");
  initiateHandler();
  const drggableBlocksHolder = document.getElementById("blocks");
  blocksData.map((block) => {
    if (!document.querySelector("#blocks > div:nth-child(4)")) drggableBlocksHolder.innerHTML += `<div draggable="true" class="block" data-block="${block.id}">${block.htmlContent}</div>`;
  });
  document.right = document.getElementsByClassName("right")[0];
  document.draggables = blocks.getElementsByClassName("block");
  document.draggable = document.querySelector('.dragging');
  for (let index = 0; index < document.draggables.length; index++) {
    const draggable = document.draggables[index];
    draggable.addEventListener('dragstart', () => {
      draggable.classList.add('dragging')
    });
    draggable.addEventListener('dragend', () => {
      draggable.classList.remove('dragging')
      document.querySelector(".dragging").classList.remove("dragging")
    });
  }
  document.right.addEventListener('dragover', (e) => {
    console.log("Test 4");
    e.preventDefault();
    document.draggables = blocks.getElementsByClassName("block");
    document.draggable = document.querySelector('.dragging');
    const afterElement = getDragAfterElement(document.right, e.clientY)
    document.draggableClone = document.draggable.cloneNode(true)
    if(document.right.querySelector(".dragging") == undefined){
        if (afterElement == null) {
        id = document.draggable.getAttribute('data-block')
            document.draggableClone.innerHTML = blocksData[id - 1].htmlContent;
            document.right.appendChild(document.draggableClone)
        } else {
            document.right.insertBefore(document.draggableClone, afterElement)
        }
    }
  });
};
const mV = (event, left) => {
  console.log("Test 5");
  if (ismdwn === 1) {
    left.style.flexBasis = event.clientX + "px"
  } else {
    end()
  }
}
const end = (e) => {
    console.log("Test 6");
    ismdwn = 0
    document.body.removeEventListener('mouseup', end)
    handle.removeEventListener('mousemove', mV)
  }
  (function() {
    console.log("Test 7");
    onReady()
  })();
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html {
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.container>.left {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 35%;
  min-width: 300px;
}

.container>.left>.blocks {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}

.container>.left>h4 {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 10px auto;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container>.left>.blocks>.block {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  cursor: move;
}

.block.dragging {
  opacity: .5;
}

.container>.right {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.container>.handle {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  content: '';
  width: 7px;
  cursor: col-resize;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <h4>Blocks</h4>
    <div class="blocks" id="blocks">
      <div draggable="true" class="block" data-block="1">Test Block 1 H1</div>
      <div draggable="true" class="block" data-block="2">Test Block 1 H2</div>
      <div draggable="true" class="block" data-block="3">Test Block 1 H3</div>
      <div draggable="true" class="block" data-block="4">Test Block 1 button</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="handle" id="handle"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Getting this error -> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'draggable')

Comment: Can you be more specific since it works on the snippet.

Comment: Yeah it's working on snippet but when I tried to run on local it's getting error.

Comment: Can you give me the line which causes this error.

Comment: this one -> handle.draggable = true;

Comment: You are missing the html element with "handle" class.

Comment: Having HTML element with "handle" class

Comment: Well that line gives " Cannot set properties of null" error which means that it can't find the const handle on the DOM. So you either don't have an element with an id of "handle"  or you are trying to find an element with different id. This is all i can do untill you post the code that you are working with. If this still does not solves your problem give me a js.fiddle or codepen link with your code.

Comment: Checked again, now it's working fine. Thanks for your timely help!!!